# Why dividing a number with a float powered by a big number ends up being a really big number instead of a small number?

Tags: arithmetic

I had a problem where I needed to find the result of the division of 2 positive large numbers.

$n1$=$29865^2$  ------- $n2=$$1.5*10^{11}$

When  I divided them I got the result of $5.946*10^{19}$

but the correct was $5.946*10^{-3}$ which can be obtained by the division of $1.5*10^{-11}$

Do I always need to convert the exponent to be negative when dividing it by another number? can someone explain me why it happened?

Thank you

Comment: Using a pocket calculator?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am using the scientific Casio fx-991ES PLUS calculator

Comment: Maybe [Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't think that's the case because when I change the exponent to be negative I get the right answer.

so I think it  belongs to something mathematically here

Comment: Maybe you missed parentheses.

Comment: Most calculators read something like a/b*c as $\frac ab\times c$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That should be the answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: Do not enter $1.5∗10^{11}$ as a multiplication, but learn to enter it using the built in function.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I don't know what's the built in function

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA , I got the correct answer using parentheses! thank you, I wonder why it doesn't give the same answer without them, because the multiplication should still make that look as it is still  the same  variable. but your answer helped me to get the right answer so thank you for that

Comment: The calculator should have a built-in way to enter numbers in scientific notation, so you enter $1.5*10^{11}$ by typing `1.5E11` where `E` is the button that is marked with "$\times 10^x$" or sometimes "Exp".

Answer (score 1):

Try some other ways, equivalent to what you tried 'till now.

For example, compute a reciprocal of $n_2$ and multiply it by $n_1$, like $\frac 1{n_2}\times n_1.$

Or divide $n_2$ by $n_1$ and then take a reciprocal: $\frac 1{n_2/n_1}.$

Or let the whole calculation through logarithm and then exponentiation: $$n_1 : n_2 = 10^{\log n_1 - \log n_2} \\ = 10^{2\log 29865 - (11 + \log 1.5)}.$$

And so on.

If *any* of those ways gives an answer you expect, you'll know almost for sure the calculator is OK and it's your way of making calculation what is wrong.
Or, if several ways give consistent but unexpected result, then you'll know the calculation is beyond the reach of your device.